# How to activate logs at every node in omnet++

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++

I need help regarding omnet++. How i can measure or record that how many packets a node in a network has sent or received? or How to activate logs at every node in omnet++?

I want to measure statistics of every node.

Please help me regarding this.
waiting for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global int variable such as **sentPackets** in the node class which will keep track of the packets that are sent. And in order to inspect it later on, use the WATCH() macro.

More info: http://www.omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec295